# How can I set Source Priority for Source Selection Algorithm in Magento MSI (Multi Stock Inventory)?

Tags: magento2, msi, selection, msi-source

I have been exploring MSI. I came across the **Source Selection Algorithm** when creating a shipment.

It has two options:

1. **Distance priority**
2. **Source priority**

When I select **source priority** nothing happens.

Where and how can I set this priority?
The order of the sources is set when we created the Inventory stock **(Stores > Inventory: Stocks)**

[image: Screenshot Source Selection Algorithm]

Comment: Also, you may find this documentation useful to get acquainted with MSI https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-management.html
https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Get-Started-with-MSI

Comment: is any idea why its not showing any source selection option while create a shipment?

Comment: @Camit1dk I am not sure what you are asking to be honest.

Comment: i can not see any option like this : https://prnt.sc/uz1ufv which provide me option to select source while create the shipment.

Comment: I think that might be due to configuration I guess. Unfortunately I have not much experience with MSI myself (yet).

Answer (score 1):

you can set-up priorities of Sources in the scope of the given Stock on that Stock editing page in Admin panel or via Web API.

Here you can read more about that:
https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Create-Stock (Assigned Sources and Priorities - section).

After adding sources to the stock, arrange those sources from top-to-bottom in priority for fulfilling orders using Drag-n-Drop. The Source Selection Algorithm (SSA) provides an algorithm Priority using this order when determining shipment and inventory deductions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already have the order/priority set. The point is nothing happens when I select "Source Priority". Should the source be selected automatically? Is this a bug in my system or is it maybee misconfigured?